# Trying to decode an input string to Decrypt using AES

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I'm working with a vendor who is supplying us with a sample AES encrypted message, we have a shared key, and I am just testing encryption/decription.

The decrypted message they are providing looks like this.  Usually I would be expecting a string, but this is what they have provided:

```
d4 ee 84 87 f4 e2 0d c2 ef 07 e4 2c 9f b2 48 9e
```

1. I'm a little confused, what kind of notation is that?
2. My encryption/decrption method is using string as the input, and string as the output, but internally I am using a byte array:

   ```
   byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);
   ```

How can I convert that above input into a byte array?

Comment: I was told it is ECB.

Comment: In 2015 and you have never seen Hexadecimal [(Video in Khan Academy)](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/pre-algebra/applying-math-reasoning-topic/alternate-number-bases/v/hexadecimal-number-system) representation before? Please take 20 minutes and read a little on this and work out a simple example by hand, and then you will remember it for the rest of your life.

Comment: @ja72 thanks, that was helpful

Comment: @ArtjomB. that was my mistake, I changed the encrypted message and missed a byte.  It is 16 now I updated it.

Comment: OK, do you have a key? What format is it in?

Comment: Yes, it is a simple string of 16 characters like "thanksverymuchab"

Answer (score 3):

It is hexadecimal represantation of bytes

```
string bytes = "d4 ee 84 87 f4 e2 0d c2 ef 07 e4 2c 9f b2 48 9e";
var buf = bytes.Split(' ').Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
```

if your hex string doesn't contain any spaces

```
string bytes = "d4ee8487f4e20dc2ef07e42c9fb2489e";
var buf = Regex.Matches(bytes, ".{2}").Cast<Match>()
               .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x.Value, 16)).ToArray();
```

You can even use `System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary` class that can parse hex strings with or without spaces.

```
string bytes = "d4ee8487f4e20dc2ef07e42c9fb2489e";
var buf = SoapHexBinary.Parse(bytes).Value;
```

**BTW:**

You should note that every byte array can not be safely converted to string by `Encoding.Unicode.GetString` in case you are using it.

```
var buf = new byte[] { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };
string str = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buf);
var buf2 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
```

`buf2` will not be equal to `buf`. To convert byte arrays to string, either use `Convert.ToBase64String` or `BitConverter.ToString`

Comment: Would converting hexadecimal into a string cause any issues?  Both parties would have to be using the same encoding/decoding correct?

Comment: `Would converting hexadecimal into a string cause any issues?` it is already string. I just converted it to byte array,

Answer (score 1):

After this code runs, `theBytes` will contain your byte array:

```
byte[] theBytes = new byte[15];
string hexstring = "d4ee8487f4e20dc2ef07e42c9fb2489e";

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
 string thisByte = hexstring.Substring(i * 2, 2);
 int intValue = Convert.ToInt16(thisByte, 16);
 theBytes[i] = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue)[0];
}
```